# Как разместить область для рисования на всю нижнюю часть экрана в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpainter, qimage, qfiledialog

Как сделать так, чтобы при том случае, когда пользователь не выбирает картинку, которую надо вставить в `canvas`, он закрашивался белым и был почти на весь экран (не считая верхнее меню) белым цветом и на нём можно было рисовать.

Вот какой код моего проекта (ссылка на *github*):
https://github.com/dimarog1/YandexProject.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
...
def init_image(self):
    # вставка изображение в поле редактирования
    fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        self, 'Выбрать картинку', '',
        'Картинка (*.jpg);;Все файлы (*)')

    if not fname:
#        fname = 'images/123.jpg'
        self.image = QImage(QtCore.QSize(800, 600), QImage.Format_ARGB32)  # !!!
        self.image.fill(QtCore.Qt.cyan)        # (QtCore.Qt.white) белый   # !!!
    else :
        self.image = QImage(fname)
    
    self.drawer = Drawer(self.image.width(), self.image.height())
    self.canvas_layout.addWidget(self.drawer, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    self.drawer.setImage(self.image)  

...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]